# reverse relationship lookup with bookshelf.js polymorphic relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm using a Polymorphic relation to allow an `Account` to be associated with two different user types: `Customer` and `Staff`. I have the models defined as follows:

```
var Customer = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'customer',
  accounts: function() {
    return this.morphMany(Account, 'concernable');
  }
});

var Staff = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'staff',
  accounts: function() {
    return this.morphMany(Account, 'concernable');
  }
});

var Account = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'account',
  concernable: function () {
    return this.morphTo('concernable', 'Staff', 'Customer');
  }
});
```

My database is Postgres and the schema I'm using for the `Account` table is:

```
id (int)
business_id (int)
concernable_id (int)
concernable_type (string)
```

What I'm attempting to do is fetch all accounts that belong to a specific business and return the customers associated with those accounts. It's the reverse of the standard relation lookup I've seen in the Bookshelf examples. Here's what I've tried with no luck:

```
   Account.where({
      business_id: filter.businessId,
      concernable_type: 'customer'
    })
    .fetchAll({
      withRelated: ['concernable']
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return reply.jsonapi(response, 'customer');
    });
```

I receive the following error: `The target polymorphic model was not found`. If I change `withRelated` to `customer`, then the error is  that `customer is not found on the model`.

Is what I'm attempting to do possible?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same problem.